# Can an optimal algorithm be not complete?

Tags: algorithm

A complete algorithm is an algorithm which finds a solution if there is any.
A optimal algorithm is an algorithm which any solution its returns is optimal or in other words there exist no better solution than the returned one.

That means optimality is based on completness, right? 
Which means an algorithm can not be optimal but not complete. Or did i get it wrong?

Comment: This looks more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm that always returns nothing, is optimal but not at all complete.

Comment: We assume that an optimal algorithm returns a valid solution. Therefore your answer is incorrect, in general.

Comment: @koverman47: For your definition my answer might me incorrect. But according to the definition given in the question (which is equal to the one I was taught at university) an algorithm return no solution is optimal.

Comment: are you referring to optimality in the time to return a solution?

Comment: @koverman47: In the definitions in the question of 'complete' and 'optimal' neither time nor is space is limited.

Answer (score 2):

No, optimalness is not based on completness:

Imagine an complete algorithm that finds a solution if there is any for a family of problems and an optimal algorithm which finds an optimal solution. Now the complete algorithm finds a solution for all problems of the family. However the optimal algorithm *might* solve only one specific problem of the family.

In other words: The optimal algorithm gives you no kind of guarantee on how many problems he could solve.

---

If for example your algorithm would multiply two numbers. Now your complete algorithm will return an answer for every a and b you might want to multiply.

Your optimal algorithm might now compute the *optimal* solution for two specific values for a and b and simply return no solution for all other values.

Comment: Your example has limited the domain of the "optimal algorithm" to two numbers instead of a larger set. Given its domain, the algorithm you described IS complete. An optimal algorithm is complete.

Comment: But an optimal algorithm has not to return any useful information in a general case. It only has to find a optimal solution for a single problem in the problem family. You are right, i have limited the set of problems, but both algorithms provide solutions for a multiplication. Therefore the example seems to be still valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of an optimal algorithm predicates on the fact that the algorithm has found an optimal solution if one exists. Therefore an optimal algorithm must be complete. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22942427/8038154) for a post that already contains the answer.